# entire teaser as link to node

Tags: javascript, navigation, nodes

I would like to use the whole tease as a link to the node. I could google (and adapted) the following code but still not working.

following line:
scripts[] = js/new_teaser.js is added in the ".info" file of my theme (Business)
and this code to the "new_teaser.js":

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".node-teaser").click(function(){
      window.location=$(this).find("a").attr("href"); return false;
    });

    });
```

the class of my teaser is ".node-teaser" and the "NoScript" addin of my browser is switched off. I assumes that the problem is in the JS code.

Drupal 7, theme Business

**Could someone help me please?**

**EDIT:** as far as I can see, there is no link to the new_teaser.js file in the source code of the page... (even if the file is in the js/ folder and in the theme .info file

Comment: Though I don't think you should do it this way, have you tried clearing cache?

Comment: Of course, cache cleared, cron ran...

Comment: I found that soution here: https://drupal.org/node/606758 but it doesn't work for me...

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. Add it to your template.php file. Using preprocess_node gives you a little more control so you aren't just arbitrarily loading the script on every page.

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['type'] == 'blog' && $variables['view_mode'] == 'teaser') {
    drupal_add_js($theme_path.'/js/new_teaser.js');
  }
}
```